# What are some possible reasons that a previously working(deployed version) of a React Native app would fail to build?

Tags: android, react-native

I deployed a working version of a React Native app about 2 months ago.  Recently, I ran into an issue with the current version I'm working on that wouldn't allow me to build without receiving

> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found
>
> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.
>   Command:
>   /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx.jar/d3ea99fc2d1356bcc9bc022a544dfd8b/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx/aapt2
>   link -I\
>             /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar\
>             --manifest\
>             /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
>             -o\
>             /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
>             -R\
>             @/Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>             --auto-add-overlay\
>             --java\
>             /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
>             --proguard-main-dex\
>             /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules/debug/processDebugResources/manifest_keep.txt\
>             --custom-package\
>             com.someapp\
>             -0\
>             apk\
>             --output-text-symbols\
>             /Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
>             --no-version-vectors   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx Daemon #0

I wasn't able to solve this problem, so I decided to go back and try to build the previously released version on a physical device.  When I attempted to build that version, I received the same exact error message(s)!?!?!

I believe the issue is with the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Someapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 34
        versionName "1.3.4"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    implementation project(':blelibrary')
    implementation project(':gaialibrary')
    implementation project(':vmupgradelibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation project(':react-native-connectivity-status')

    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1")
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

repositories {
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I was able to get a new version of the app to work, but only after I had migrated/updated to compiledSdkVersion to 28...which presented it's own set of problems:  I could not longer get the debugger to work.  Also, I would prefer to keep the older version of the app.

This leads me to believe that the issue is not related to the react-native code, rather a change that I've unknowingly made to my system.

The iOS version of the app builds with no problem, so this is strictly an Android version problem.

Comment: Could you please change the Comply, Build and Target version to 28?

Comment: Build version 28.0.3

Comment: build Tool version..right?  Can i keep everything else the same?

Comment: If you update these versions, you may be warned to update the version of the module. You can update it together. Current version 28 is recommended.

Comment: I updated only the buildToolsVersion to 28.0.3 ..got the same error message as before

Comment: You should change the compilation version and target version to 28.

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: no..unfortunately not. Now I'm getting error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;
 errror

Comment: Isn't that a React-native code error, not an Android studio error?